# Using Scala's Swing wrapper, how can I update a panel's contents via foreach with a collection?

Tags: swing, scala, foreach

I have a panel and a list full of filenames that reference .png files.
I can turn the string in any singe index of that list in to an image using:

```
val label = new Label {
  icon = new ImageIcon(myList(0))
}
```

Then I can add that label to the panel:

```
object myGUI extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "My simple GUI"
    contents += label
  }
}
```

but what if I want to construct a label for each entry in the list, and add each of those labels to myGUI?

I'd like to do so using foreach or some other idiomatic scala concept.  If a different collection type makes more sense, I don't need to use a List.  As I understand it, however, the collection processing functions are the same for an Array or Map as they are for a List so the collection type shouldn't matter (in the scope of this particular GUI related problem, anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly your question, but does this not work?:

```
object myGUI extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "My simple GUI"
      val list = ... //your list of filepaths
      list foreach { filepath =>
        contents += new Label { icon = new ImageIcon(filepath) }
      }    
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks promising...  trying it now.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Awesome!  thanks!  Before I accept the answer, how can I edit my question to make it more clear?